# Why is AREL adding OR IN (NULL) to BETWEEN conditions?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, arel

I have a scope in the model:

```
scope :daily, lambda {|day| where :post_time => 
  [day.beginning_of_day() .. day.end_of_day()] }
```

`:post_time` is declare not-nullable in the database, but AREL insists on adding a spurious `IN (NULL)` to the generated SQL:

```
SELECT `<table>`.* FROM `<table>` 
WHERE (`<table>`.`post_time` 
     BETWEEN '2013-02-05 00:00:00' AND '2013-02-05 23:59:59' 
     OR `<table>`.`post_time` IN (NULL))
```

How can I stop it from doing this? Obviously I can add one more condition `not_eq(nil)`, `:post_time != nil` or similar, but my question is *why* does AREL do it, and how can I prevent it without extra conditions to negate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're confusing arel by passing in an array of ranges (although why this adds the extra clause I'm not sure).

```
scope :daily, lambda {|day| where :post_time => 
  (day.beginning_of_day() .. day.end_of_day()) }
```

should be ok.

Comment: To my embarassment I  must reckon that until now I thought that `[from..to]` **is** the syntax for a [range](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Range.html)...